# Цикл в PHP

Tags: php

Как в данном случае сделать что бы все выводилось в цикле.

```
$pages=array(
"$file_name"=>"$item_name"
);
```

Дело в том что здесь выводятся из БД первые строки, а надо что бы выводились все подряд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос.**

Цикл для перебора массивов

```
foreach($page as $key => $value){
print "ключ $key \n";
print "зачение $value";
}
```

**UPD**
Если инфа берётся из базы данных, то примеров обработки куча. [Например для mysql](http://php.su/functions/?cat=mysql):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
    }
```

Comment: А как сделать цикл внутри массива для перебора переменных ???

Comment: Перефразируй и конкретизируй. Никто не любит непонятные вопросы.